# Get max width/height of elements in array using Math.max

Tags: javascript

Hei guys, i thought that will be simple but im facing a problem getting max value of elements offsetWidth. The console doesnt return max width or height as it should be.

**Example:**

```
<div style="left:30px;top:166px;position:absolute">
            <img src="assets/text1.png" />
        </div>
        <div style="left:350px;top:266px;position:absolute">
            <img src="assets/text2.png" />
        </div>
        <div style="left:350px;top:366px;position:absolute">
            <img src="assets/text3.png" />
        </div>

<script>
   elements = document.querySelectorAll("#container > div");
elementsArray = [];

for (var j = 0; j < nrOfElements; j++) {
    elementsArray.push(elements[j]);
}

    var width = elementsArray[0].offsetWidth;
    var height = elementsArray[0].offsetHeight;

    for (var i = 0; i < nrOfElements; i++) {
        var maxWidth = Math.max(width, elementsArray[i].offsetWidth);
        var maxHeight = Math.max(height, elementsArray[i].offsetHeight);
        var minWidth = Math.min(width, elementsArray[i].offsetWidth);
        var minHeight = Math.min(height, elementsArray[i].offsetHeight);
    }
        console.log("maxWidth " + maxWidth);
        console.log("maxHeight " + maxHeight);
        console.log("minWidth " + minWidth);
        console.log("minHeight " + minHeight);
</script>
```

**Note**

It should return:

```
maxWidth = 380 (second element);
maxHeight = 70 (third element);
minWidth = 200 (third element);
minHeight = 59 (first element);
```

And it returns:

```
maxWidth = 296 (first element);
maxHeight = 59 (second and third element height);
minWidth = 200 (its ok);
minHeight = 59 (its ok);
```

Whats wrong? Where i'm wrong?

Pure js please!

Thanks

**Edit**

As guys suggested, the new code looks like:

```
var width = minW = elementsArray[0].offsetWidth;
    var height = minH = elementsArray[0].offsetHeight;

    var maxWidth;
    var maxHeight;
    var minWidth;
    var minHeight;

    for (var i = 0; i < nrOfElements; i++) {
        var eachElem = elementsArray[i];
        maxWidth = Math.max(width, elementsArray[i].offsetWidth);
        maxHeight = Math.max(height, elementsArray[i].offsetHeight);
        minWidth = Math.min(width, elementsArray[i].offsetWidth);
        minHeight = Math.min(height, elementsArray[i].offsetHeight);
    }
        console.log("maxWidth " + maxWidth);
        console.log("maxHeight " + maxHeight);
        console.log("minWidth " + minWidth);
        console.log("minHeight " + minHeight);
```

**Edit 2**

I'm getting mad! Did the fiddle to check it, with F12 it should check the console, or change the console to alert...

http://jsfiddle.net/ef4wvuy6/

Comment: declare `maxWidth`, `maxHeight` etc variables before the for loop

Comment: It's interesting how your min is working then.I dont see it is also declared

Comment: Aint working even if i declare the maxWidth/maxHeight/minWidth/minHeight ... it returns same values :|

Comment: No way. Images are fully loaded when it reaches those lines... And yes, i did checked the console inside the loop for every width and height and it return well. (296,380,200 - width) inside the for loop with the dimensions from fiddle i added in the issue EDIT 2

Comment: You're comparing all widths and heights to the width and height of the first element, not to the previous maximum/minimum value. Should be `Math.max(maxWidth, ...)` and so on.

Comment: @Juhana lemme check that.

Comment: Annnd the result is NaN :| i also tried to use maxWidth = Math.max(null, elementsArray[i].offsetWidth);

Comment: That's because the variables are not initialized. (`var maxWidth = 0;` etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ef4wvuy6/8/). You have to make sure you are using the temporary min/max variables in the Math.min/max functions, and not just the width/height you initially set (that was the mistake in your latest JSFiddle).

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#container > div");
var nrOfElements = elements.length;
var elementsArray = [];

for (var j = 0; j < nrOfElements; j++) {
    elementsArray.push(elements[j]);
}

var maxWidth = 0;
var maxHeight = 0;
var minWidth = 0;
var minHeight = 0;

if (nrOfElements > 1) {
    var width = elementsArray[0].offsetWidth;
    var height = elementsArray[0].offsetHeight;

    maxWidth = width;
    maxHeight = height;
    minWidth = width;
    minHeight = height;
    for (var i = 1; i < nrOfElements; i++) {
        maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, elementsArray[i].offsetWidth);
        maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, elementsArray[i].offsetHeight);
        minWidth = Math.min(minWidth, elementsArray[i].offsetWidth);
        minHeight = Math.min(minHeight, elementsArray[i].offsetHeight);
    }
}

console.log("maxWidth " + maxWidth);
console.log("maxHeight " + maxHeight);
console.log("minWidth " + minWidth);
console.log("minHeight " + minHeight);
```

Comment: Note the values for minHeight and maxHeight, those values are media of max and min Height

Comment: That is because the height of your `div` != height of your `img`. If you want the min/max heights of your `img`s, replace `#container > div` by `#container > div > img` in the first line of the code.

Comment: Nope, i'd like to get the width/height of the div. I have noticed that images has height less than div height and i dont care. The width/height of the div is what i need

Comment: And where is the problem then? The code returns the right values for the divs.

Comment: Have you checked the console of fiddle? It returns: maxWidth 380
(index):54 maxHeight 74
(index):55 minWidth 200
(index):56 minHeight 63 . Are minHeight and maxHeight the right values? No, the maxHeight should be 70 and the minHeight: 59

Comment: Sorry for indentation... i dont know how to use it in a comment on this site. What i wanna say is that min and max Height gets the value of a media between elements heights

Comment: That's the size of the images inside the div, not the divs. So yes, they are the correct values. If you want those dimensions, try as I said and replace `#container > div` by `#container > div > img`.

Comment: Unfortunately yes... but the #container > div > img wont look good for further steps ... Thats why i didnt use div > img. I will later add transitions on the divs

Comment: Thanks for help guys, i have understood where i was wrong. Thanks alot

Comment: you can use `if (nrOfElements){` instead of `if (nrOfElements > 1) {`

Answer (score 1):

You can get max(or min) element from array through this code `eval("Math.max("+arrWidth.toString()+")");`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e61o8dgh/)

UPDATED: You should use `elementsArray[i].firstElementChild.offsetHeight` for getting `offsetHeight` of `img`

Comment: Some steps added and the result aint good at all. Check the console and you'll see for max values (width/height) a node list with all the dimensions

Comment: You should update the selector instead of using firstElementChild if you want to get the img, else it'll crash if the div is empty.

Comment: yeap, seems to be what i was looking for. Thanks